# libhdfs JNI FindClass returns null with java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, hadoop, java-native-interface

I'm trying to test libhdfs on windows, which is using JNI to call java functions, the JVM created but when loading hadoop classes, the findclass always fail.

I've googled and searched stackoverflow, couldn't figure out the problem for me, please help.

**System:**

```
Windows 7 32-bit
Visual Studio 2013 Express
JDK 1.6.0_32
Hadoop 2.5.0 (it's working fine using command)
```

**Issue:**

```
when program executed to getGlobalJNIEnv -> globalClassReference -> FindClass

    local_clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, className); // classname = org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem

org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem is in C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\hadoop-common-2.5.0.jar, which is in CLASSPATH

FindClass always return null.
```

**libhdfs** code:

```
static JNIEnv* getGlobalJNIEnv(void)
{
    JavaVM* vmBuf[VM_BUF_LENGTH];
    JNIEnv *env;
    jint rv = 0;
    jint noVMs = 0;
    jthrowable jthr;
    char *hadoopClassPath;
    const char *hadoopClassPathVMArg = "-Djava.class.path=";
    size_t optHadoopClassPathLen;
    char *optHadoopClassPath;
    const int noArgs = 6;
    char *hadoopJvmArgs;
    char jvmArgDelims[] = " ";
    char *str, *token, *savePtr;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVM *vm;
    JavaVMOption *options;

    rv = JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs(&(vmBuf[0]), VM_BUF_LENGTH, &noVMs);
    if (rv != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs failed with error: %d\n", rv);
        return NULL;
    }

    if (noVMs == 0) {
        //Get the environment variables for initializing the JVM
        hadoopClassPath = getenv("CLASSPATH");
        if (hadoopClassPath == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Environment variable CLASSPATH not set!\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        optHadoopClassPathLen = strlen(hadoopClassPath) +
            strlen(hadoopClassPathVMArg) + 1;
        optHadoopClassPath = malloc(sizeof(char)*optHadoopClassPathLen);
        snprintf(optHadoopClassPath, optHadoopClassPathLen,
            "%s%s", hadoopClassPathVMArg, hadoopClassPath);



        // Now that we know the # args, populate the options array
        options = calloc(noArgs, sizeof(JavaVMOption));
        if (!options) {
            fputs("Call to calloc failed\n", stderr);
            free(optHadoopClassPath);
            return NULL;
        }

        options[0].optionString = optHadoopClassPath;
        options[1].optionString = "-Djava.library.path=C:\\Progra~1\\Java\\jdk1.6.0_32\\lib";
        options[2].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";
        options[3].optionString = "-verbose:jni";
        options[4].optionString = "-verbose:class";
        options[5].optionString = "-verbose:gc";



        //Create the VM
        vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
        vm_args.options = options;
        vm_args.nOptions = noArgs;
        vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

        rv = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&vm, (void*)&env, &vm_args);

        if (rv != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Call to JNI_CreateJavaVM failed "
                "with error: %d\n", rv);
            return NULL;
        }
        jthr = invokeMethod(env, NULL, STATIC, NULL,
            "org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem",
            "loadFileSystems", "()V");

        free(optHadoopClassPath);
        free(options);

        if (jthr) {
            printExceptionAndFree(env, jthr, PRINT_EXC_ALL, "loadFileSystems");
        }

    }
    else {
        //Attach this thread to the VM
        vm = vmBuf[0];
        rv = (*vm)->AttachCurrentThread(vm, (void*)&env, 0);
        if (rv != 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Call to AttachCurrentThread "
                "failed with error: %d\n", rv);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    return env;
}


jthrowable globalClassReference(const char *className, JNIEnv *env, jclass *out)
{
    jthrowable jthr = NULL;
    jclass local_clazz = NULL;
    jclass clazz = NULL;
    int ret;

    mutexLock(&hdfsHashMutex);
    if (!gClassRefHTable) {
        gClassRefHTable = htable_alloc(MAX_HASH_TABLE_ELEM, ht_hash_string,
            ht_compare_string);
        if (!gClassRefHTable) {
            jthr = newRuntimeError(env, "htable_alloc failed\n");
            goto done;
        }
    }
    clazz = htable_get(gClassRefHTable, className);
    if (clazz) {
        *out = clazz;
        goto done;
    }

    local_clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, className);

    if (!local_clazz) {

        (*env)->ExceptionDescribe(env);

        jthr = getPendingExceptionAndClear(env);
        goto done;
    }
    clazz = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, local_clazz);
    if (!clazz) {
        jthr = getPendingExceptionAndClear(env);
        goto done;
    }
    ret = htable_put(gClassRefHTable, (void*)className, clazz);
    if (ret) {
        jthr = newRuntimeError(env, "htable_put failed with error "
            "code %d\n", ret);
        goto done;
    }
    *out = clazz;
    jthr = NULL;
done:
    mutexUnlock(&hdfsHashMutex);
    (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, local_clazz);
    if (jthr && clazz) {
        (*env)->DeleteGlobalRef(env, clazz);
    }
    return jthr;
}

jthrowable getPendingExceptionAndClear(JNIEnv *env)
{
    jthrowable jthr = (*env)->ExceptionOccurred(env);
    if (!jthr)
        return NULL;
    (*env)->ExceptionClear(env);
    return jthr;
}

int printExceptionAndFreeV(JNIEnv *env, jthrowable exc, int noPrintFlags,
        const char *fmt, va_list ap)
{
    int i, noPrint, excErrno;
    char *className = NULL;
    jstring jStr = NULL;
    jvalue jVal;
    jthrowable jthr;

    jthr = classNameOfObject(exc, env, &className);
    if (jthr) {
        fprintf(stderr, "PrintExceptionAndFree: error determining class name "
            "of exception.\n");
        className = strdup("(unknown)");
        destroyLocalReference(env, jthr);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < EXCEPTION_INFO_LEN; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(gExceptionInfo[i].name, className)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (i < EXCEPTION_INFO_LEN) {
        noPrint = (gExceptionInfo[i].noPrintFlag & noPrintFlags);
        excErrno = gExceptionInfo[i].excErrno;
    } else {
        noPrint = 0;
        excErrno = EINTERNAL;
    }
    if (!noPrint) {
        vfprintf(stderr, fmt, ap);
        fprintf(stderr, " error:\n");

        // We don't want to  use ExceptionDescribe here, because that requires a
        // pending exception.  Instead, use ExceptionUtils.
        jthr = invokeMethod(env, &jVal, STATIC, NULL, 
            "org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils",
            "getStackTrace", "(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/String;", exc);
        if (jthr) {
            fprintf(stderr, "(unable to get stack trace for %s exception: "
                    "ExceptionUtils::getStackTrace error.)\n", className);
            destroyLocalReference(env, jthr);
        } else {
            jStr = jVal.l;
            const char *stackTrace = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, jStr, NULL);
            if (!stackTrace) {
                fprintf(stderr, "(unable to get stack trace for %s exception: "
                        "GetStringUTFChars error.)\n", className);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s", stackTrace);
                (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, jStr, stackTrace);
            }
        }
    }
    destroyLocalReference(env, jStr);
    destroyLocalReference(env, exc);
    free(className);
    return excErrno;
}

int printExceptionAndFree(JNIEnv *env, jthrowable exc, int noPrintFlags,
        const char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int ret;

    va_start(ap, fmt);
    ret = printExceptionAndFreeV(env, exc, noPrintFlags, fmt, ap);
    va_end(ap);
    return ret;
}
```

**Environment vairables:**

```
C:\>hadoop classpath
c:\hadoop\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\
common\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;C:\hadoop
\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\ya
rn\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*

CLASSPATH = c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\lib;c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre\lib;c:\hadoop\etc\hadoop;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\lib\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\hdfs\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\yarn\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*;C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*

JAVA_HOME = c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
```

**Console output:** (updated after adding ExceptionDescribe after findclass)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/
FileSystem
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/
FileSystem
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
could not find method loadFileSystems from class org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem
 with signature ()V
loadFileSystems error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/la
ng/exception/ExceptionUtils
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.E
xceptionUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/la
ng/exception/ExceptionUtils
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.E
xceptionUtils
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
could not find method getStackTrace from class org/apache/commons/lang/exception
/ExceptionUtils with signature (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)Ljava/lang/String;
(unable to get stack trace for java.lang.NoSuchMethodError exception: ExceptionU
tils::getStackTrace error.)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/con
f/Configuration
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuratio
n
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/con
f/Configuration
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuratio
n
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: Always fails how? Where's the evidence? Where is `getPendingExceptionAndClear()`. What's the question?

Comment: @ejp, sorry I wasn't very clear, I'm updating the issue in the question,
the problem is in 'local_clazz = (*env)->FindClass(env, className);', when passing hadoop class , findclass always returns null

Comment: OK, now where is `printExceptionAndFree()`? And why does it even exist? JNI already has a function to print the current exception: `ExceptionDescribe().` You seem to be doing everything the hard way.

Comment: @EJP, I added printExceptionAndFree code, they're all part of libhdfs code from : https://github.com/apache/hadoop/tree/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/native/libhdfs , I just downloaded and edit it a bit so it can be compiled on windows, most of the code is apache official code, the code i posted are in jni_helper.c and exception.c

Comment: You are getting an exception trying to print the stack trace of an exception. I can only suggest that you throw most of this pointless, ill-designed, and error-prone drivel away and call `ExceptionDescribe()` immediately at the point where `FindClass()` fails. And provide the resulting stack trace, in your question.

Comment: @EJP, added ExceptionDescribe right after findclass, console output updated

Comment: Added it where? All I can see is more useless crap frankly. Now you're failing trying to load yet another class while trying to print the stack trace of the original exception. This is getting us absolutely nowhere. After the code calls `FindClass()` and fails, you should *immediately* call `ExceptionDescribe()`. All this stuff is very poorly designed, wherever it comes from.

Comment: @EJP, I added to globalClassReference function, right after calling findclass, code in question updated

Comment: There is no `FileNotFoundException` in evidence here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
```

You don't have that class available on the CLASSPATH.

Comment: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem is in hadoop-common-2.5.0.jar, which is in C:\hadoop\share\hadoop\common\, the path is in CLASSPATH.  This part i double checked

Comment: The exception doesn't agree with you.